# Drawing arbitrary shapes on a layer using Geoserver for WMS

Tags: geoserver, wms

We are using Geoserver 2.8.1 with Leaflet to do some basic map manipulation on the client-side. One requirement is the ability to render an image based off of the map to be used in other places (say dump into a spreadsheet). So far, this hasn't been an issue since we use the WMS GetMap service to request a png using the appropriate parameters to re-create an image of what the user sees on the leaflet map.

My issue comes when drawing a circle to represent data that is present inside a particular radius. Using leaflet, this is not a problem. My problem comes when attempting to draw this circle using Geoserver. Say I have a layer named `US_Layer`. Is it possible for me to somehow draw shapes on the fly on top of this layer using Geoserver? If I have the GeoJSON info for this circle, is there a way for me to pass this information to Geoserver so that it can then place it on a given layer for it to be rendered using the WMS GetMap service?